# connect by multi regexp_substr for one col

Tags: string, oracle, regexp-substr

I tried using the below code, but I'm unable get the value for each alias, it just allow me to use connect by for only one alias

```
select regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,1 ) as first_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,2 ) as second_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,3 ) as third_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,4 ) as forth_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,5 ) as fifth_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,6 ) as sixth_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,7 ) as seventh_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,8 ) as eighth_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,9 ) as ninth_occur,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,10 ) as thenth_occur
       from demo_live
       CONNECT by 
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,1 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,2 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,3 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,4 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,5 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,6 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,7 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,8 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,9 )is not null,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'[^,]+[^,]', 1,10 )is not null;
```

i have only on column,the date looks like:

```
val1,val2,,val3,val4,val5
TS1,TS2,,,,TS3,TS4,TS5

expected result:
col1  col2   col3  col4  col4                 
val1  val2   val3  val4  val5
TS1   TS2    TS3   TS4   TS5
```

Comment: You need to show some sample data, and what the expected output should be.  There is not enough information to help you yet, except to say the connect by syntax is not correct which you have found out already.  If you are trying to parse a comma delimited string, there are tons of examples on that here, just do some searching.

Comment: thank you,the question has been updated the samples